# How do you manage view tags in your iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have an iOS app that uses a few viewcontrollers with lots of elements. I built the viewcontrollers in the interface builder (in a storyboard). For some key elements (loginbutton, important text, etc..) I created an IBOutlet to be able to use these elements in my code (adjust text/graphics mostly).
For some others where I just needed a quick fix (for example an activity indicator that I show and hide programmatically), I chose to not create an IBOutlet, but instead give them a tag number and access them by the `viewWithTag:(NSInteger)` method.

This seemed to work for me (it's only my second iOS project so it might be completely wrong to do this). But now that the viewcontrollers get more complex I find it hard to remember which numbers I already used for tags. Is there any way to keep track of this other than by going trough all the elements and checking their tag?

Maybe it's all wrong to use tags this way, in that case that's fine too. I could look them all up once and just create IBOutlets for all the cases where I use a tag now.

Comment: I don't. You shouldn't use them... ever. If you are relying on tags to access different UI elements or to pull data out of your view then you're doing it wrong. I would create IBOutlets for them or if there are several with the same tag then create an IBOutletCollection which is essentially an array with the elements inside.

Comment: use class public and private properties as, @propert UIView *activityView;

Comment: I totally agree with @Fogmeister, why would you loop thru all the elements to get a view. This is time consuming and you should not do it.

Comment: Here is a quick link with some alternatives to using tags. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

Comment: That's what I thought. @Fogmeister if you could post it as an answer I can accept it so future readers may be saved from making the same mistake.

Comment: Even though i disagree on using tags when there are multiple child views, i think opinion is not an answer, so the answer would be: Use other .h file to store constant integers with names like #define kButtonTag 5 This way you will know what is what.

Comment: @avuthless That would indeed be a literal answer to the question, but the question itself a [bit X/Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So Fogmeister's answer is really what I was looking for.

Comment: @avuthless I agree also. I made the answer more answer like and less opinional :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try to avoid using `view tags` as much as possible.

There are always other (and almost always better) ways to do exactly the same thing by using `properties` and `data models` instead of tags.

Here is an article that I found with some nice examples of why they're not a good idea to use... http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

If you need to access a UI element then create an `IBOutlet` for it in the interface of the class that needs it.

Alternatively, if there are several elements that are the same then you can create and `IBOutletCollection` which is just an array that contains all the elements linked to it.

**EDIT**

For anyone stumbling across this now. This is an article from a former Apple engineer explaining why using tags is not only a code smell and bad practice but also a performance issue.

https://www.fadel.io/blog/posts/ios-performance-tips-you-probably-didnt-know/